# How to search for string that spans a line using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, newline

I am stymied trying to search for a string using regex when the string spans two lines in my text file.  I have searched Stackoverflow to no end.  I have tried the regex \s and DOTALL and other things for some time now.

The problem seems to be that I am iterating line after line, which seems to me to be the right thing to do for large files.  And I get it that looking line after line shouldn't pick up something on the next line, but I thought there would be a flag in regex to use.  I can't seem to find the relevant flag.

I have also tried various if then to deal with looking around the corner so to speak.  But first that doesn't seem pythonic and second I keep getting errors like cannot concatenate strings and lists.  And doing it that way just keeps getting more and more complicated.

Here is my script:

```
captured_text = []
captured_multi_nums = []
with open('text.txt', mode='r') as ptnt_txt:
    for line in ptnt_txt:
        my_txt_pull = re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+ [0-9][0-9]*", line, re.M)
        if my_txt_pull:  #captures nonempty list
            for item in my_txt_pull:
                captured_text.append(item)                
make_text_unique = (set(captured_text))
with open('patent_fig_number_output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in make_text_unique:
        f.write(item)
        f.write('\n')
```

Here is the the text.txt file I use and what does NOT get captured is "line chaz \n56":

"chaz help for chaz new line chaz
56 you see.

To keep the telescoping arms 40 in their final extended state after deployment in a vessel, a one-way latch may be used to lock adjacent segments 42. FIG. 5 shows one possible latch 44, in a first position, for locking the telescoping arms 40. The latch 44 may consist of a one or more grooves 46 associated with a first segment 48 and a tooth 50 associated with a second, adjacent segment 52. As the telescoping arm 40 is expanded, the second segment 52 moves in a first direction A relative to the first segment 48. The tooth 50 and the grooves 46 are aligned so as to engage when the telescoping arm 40 is extended. Once the tooth 50 engages a groove 46, as shown in FIG. 6, the second segment 52 may not move in a second direction B relative to the first segment 48. Accordingly, the telescoping arm 40 is free to extend but may not collapse once extended. Of course other one-way latches may be used to lock the segments 42 of the telescoping arms 40. FIG. 7 illustrates one possible cross-section of a segment 42 of the telescoping arm 40. This "rail" design permits room for sliding and positioning of a one-way latch, like the one shown in FIG. 5, between segments 42 shown in FIG. 4."

Comment: There is no regex flag that will help you match across lines you do not feed the regex engine multiline text blocks. No miracles. Read the text in as a single variables, or parse using specific logic, not necessarily regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The statement `for line in ptnt_txt:` splits the input on newlines and
  processes line by line. Then you can't perform the regex across lines.
  Use `ptnt_txt.read()` instead to slurp whole text into a variable.
- In the regex `"[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+ [0-9][0-9]*` atoms are separated by
  whitespaces which never matches newlines. Try something like:
  "[a-zA-Z]+\s*[a-zA-Z]+\s*[0-9][0-9]*`

Then the lines between #4 and #8 will look like:

```
    s = ptnt_txt.read()
    my_txt_pull = re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+\s+[a-zA-Z]+\s+[0-9][0-9]*", s, re.M)
    if my_txt_pull:
        for item in my_txt_pull:
            captured_text.append(item.replace('\n', ' '))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up with based on @tshiono and the first comment that was eye opening:

```
patent_file = 'test2.txt'
with open(patent_file, mode='r') as ptnt_txt:
    patent_txt = ptnt_txt.read().replace('\n', ' ')
    my_txt_pull = re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+\s+[0-9][0-9]*", patent_txt, re.M)
```

Comment: Yeah. It is a good idea to replace newline characters with whitespaces *before* the pattern matching. BTW we do not need to specify `re.M` flag because it just changes the behavior of `^` and `$` anchors.